# Processing XML Hierarchy with MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xpath, sqlxml

How would I specify the following XML Hierarchy into readable columns in Microsoft SQL?

```
<transaction id=1>
    <item id=1>
        <price>1</price>
    </item>
    <item id=2>
        <price>1</price>
    </item>
</transaction>
<transaction>
    <item id=1>
        <price>1</price>
    </item>
</transaction>
```

for instance

```
select
    x.i.value('(????)','Varchar(max)') [TransId]
    x.i.value('(????)','Varchar(max)') [ItemId]
    x.i.value('(????)','Varchar(max)') [PriceId]
from @xml.nodes('/transaction') x(i)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually usually it's faster to shred XML from parent to child using `apply`, like this:

```
select
    t.c.value('@id','int') as TransId,
    i.c.value('@id','int') as ItemId,
    i.c.value('(price/text())[1]', 'int') as PriceId
from @xml.nodes('transaction') as t(c)
    outer apply t.c.nodes('item') as i(c)
order by TransId, ItemID
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/21398)</kbd>**

Comment: Thanks a million man, this is the performance issue I was having. I was trying to build the hierarchy backwards. went from 20 min run time to 2 seconds. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Attribute values must always appear in quotation marks in XML.
Not sure about the desired output. An example would be:

```
declare @xml xml
Select @xml=
'<transaction id="1">
    <item id="1">
        <price>1</price>
    </item>
    <item id="2">
        <price>2</price>
    </item>
</transaction>
<transaction>
    <item id="1">
        <price>3</price>
    </item>
</transaction>'

SELECT
    y.value('../@id','int') as TransactionID,
    y.value('@id','int') as ItemID,
    y.value('(./price/text())[1]', 'Varchar(max)') as Price
FROM @xml.nodes('/transaction/item') as x(y)
order by TransactionID,ItemID
```

with the output:

```
NULL    1   3
1       1   1
1       2   2
```

Comment: OK, so I reviewed some tutorial guides and took in your suggestion.
Im coming back with results, however its taking 20mins to shred just 1 XML file.If I remove the parent look up(../@id) then it returns results instantly.  The Problem is the parent ID isn't in the child elements as an attribute, so I MUST pull this back.  

Any suggestions on how I could tune the performance specifically for this bottleneck.  Or how to understand why this is a bottleneck.  I've tried doing a XSD setup into a SQL schema and then creating primary and secondary XML indexes and got the same speed results.